# How would you translate "for just a moment" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-choice, usage, meaning-in-context

I am wondering if there's a more accurate way to say "**for just a moment**", or **"if not for just a moment**" in Chinese?

I am not certain because the translations I found sounds unnatural when spoken.
However, upon searching and using my thoughts, I tried writing it like:

"----，**就算只是一片刻**"

I think "片刻" would mean "moment" here.

Example of a sentence that I wanted to translate:
"You made me feel like I didn't regret my life's decisions, if not just for a moment."

Again, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better if you gave a complete English sentence for translating. There is no 'one-size-fits-all" answer.

就在那一瞬间他笑了。
Just for a moment, he smiled.

她在远处的堤岸上看到什么东西一闪就不见了。
Just for a moment she saw something on the far bank, then it was gone.

她犹豫了片刻。
She hesitated for a moment.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you want to translate, I think it needs to be understood in context. I tried to translate it like this: 你让我觉得我没有后悔我的人生决定，即使不是一刻。 Actually, I just look at this sentence and find it very strange. If you want an accurate translation, you can send the context.

Comment: For context, I think exemplify it like: someone that has recently graduated college and feels like they don't find meaning in their career. They additionally feel that miss out on a lot of relationships because of choosing this career path. However, they later falls in love with someone that they could of only met if they stepped in that career path, thus they start to feel that it was all worth it at the end. (Sorry if this sounds confusing, it's hard to organize the thoughts)

Answer (score 1):

"I didn't regret my decisions, even just for a moment." = "I didn't regret my decisions, not even for a moment."

我不曾對自己所作的決定感到後悔, 即使是一片刻.

"If not paused for a moment to cross the street, I would have lost my life."

要不是過馬路時犹豫了一下, 我(早)就沒命了

Comment: Your sentence doesn't mean the same thing as the one in the question. "If not just for a moment" =/= "not even for a moment". It means something like "even if it was only for a moment", opposite to the meaning in your answer.

Comment: @Curiosity Correct. My sentence is different from the one in question. The change is because I don't think " "If not just for a moment" makes good sense, so I rather interpret it my way.

Answer (score 1):

From everyone's responses so far, it helped me thought up my current translation for "You made me feel like I didn't regret my life's decisions, if not just for a moment", with something like:

> 在那一瞬间，你让我感到我所有的遗憾都消失了。

which includes the word ”遗憾” (regret) for better fitting the context.